# How can I name the files a pipe function create in gulp?

Tags: gulp, filenames, gulp-spritesmith

I have a folder with big images. the goal is to create smaller images in color, black and white and then merge everything to create a sprite.

I create 3 internal tasks to create the 3 variants of images. The issue appear when I merge them for `spritesmith` and try to optimize the output image.

(Note: This is not the original question, but I found the issue)

I realized that the files created with `gm` doesn't have any name, therefore `spritesmith` doesn't know which name to give to the CSS rules.

```
var path = require('path')
var gulp = require('gulp')
var imagemin = require('imagemin')
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var merge = require('merge-stream');


var gm = require('gulp-gm');

var spritesmith = require('gulp.spritesmith');
var spritesmash = require('gulp-spritesmash');
var pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant');

var source = "./testorig/"
var dest = "./test/"

gulp.task('sprites', function () {

    // Get files
    var files = gulp.src(source+'/*.png')

    // Create smaller images
    var _smaller = files.pipe(gm(function (gmfile) {
        return gmfile.resize(24, 24).unsharp('0x1');
    }))

    // Create smaller white images
    var _smaller_white = files.pipe(gm(function (gmfile) {
        return gmfile.resize(24, 24).unsharp('0x1').threshold(-1, true);
    }))

    // Create smallerblack images
    var _smaller_black = files.pipe(gm(function (gmfile) {
        return gmfile.resize(24, 24).unsharp('0x1').threshold(100, true);
    })) // <<<--- Files created have no names for the css creation process below

    // Merge all icons
    var merged_images = merge(_smaller, _smaller_white, _smaller_black)

    // Create sprite
    var spriteData = merged_images
        .pipe(spritesmith({
            imgName: 'sprite.png',
            cssName: 'sprite.scss',
            padding: 3,
        }))
        .pipe(spritesmash());


    // // Pipe image stream through image optimizer and onto disk
    var imgStream = spriteData.img
        .pipe(buffer()) // <-- Error here <<------------
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            interlaced: true,
            optimizationLevel: 7,
            svgoPlugins: [{
                removeViewBox: false
            }, {
                removeUselessStrokeAndFill: false
            }],
            plugins: [

                pngquant({
                    quality: [70,90],
                    speed: 1
                })
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));

    // // Pipe CSS stream through CSS optimizer and onto disk
    var cssStream = spriteData.css
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + 'sprites'));

    // // Return a merged stream to handle both `end` events
    return merge(imgStream, cssStream);

});
```

The error:

```
'sprites' errored after 14 ms
[00:45:49] TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
    at /srv/spritestest/gulpfile.js:50:10
    at taskWrapper (/srv/spritestest/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:314:12)
    at asyncRunner (/srv/spritestest/node_modules/async-done/index.js:55:18)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

I tried to `gulp.dest` after merging:

```
var spriteData = merged_images
        .pipe(spritesmith({
            imgName: 'sprite.png',
            cssName: 'sprite.scss',
            padding: 3,
        }))
        .pipe(spritesmash())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
```

I get a file but I still have an error but no trace.

How can I make this working?

I would like to avoid multiple tasks as I may have other folder with other transform to apply and I would end up with 50 different tasks. Having them self contained make management easier for me.

Comment: is this a typo? `var imgStream = spriteData.img.pipe(buffer())....` what does the `.img` do?

Comment: It's suppose to pipe only the image part of the stream. There is css and img where you can modify them before saving to file according to the docs. I've opened an issue on their repo.

Comment: Oh it’s from gulp.smith! Perhaps you have to pipe to spritesmash & gulp.dest after the merge of imgStream and cssStream? It looks like spritesmash doesn’t return substreams like gulp.smith does